# Multiple dependent select box on page jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, multiple-select

Hello I'm trying to create form where are two or more same dependent select boxes. Problem is that I can choose from first select box and can't figure out how to choose from other(s). Can anyone help me with this.

I can't select from third select box.

Here is: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0bsznjx/)

JS code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select[name*="[]"]').each(function(){

        var attribute = {
        'shoes': ['standard'],
        'trous': ['male', 'female'],
        'shirt': ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow'],
        'hoodie': ['blue', 'red'],
        }

        var size = {
            'shoes': ['35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46'],
            'trous': ['44', '46', '48', '50', '52', '54', '56', '58', '60', '62', '64'],
            'shirt': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
            'hoodie': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
        }

        $('select[name*="[]"]').change(function () {
        var $attribute = $(this).next('.attribute');
        var product = $(this).val(), attProd = attribute[product] || [];

        var html = $.map(attProd, function (attOpt) {
            return '<option value="' + attOpt + '">' + attOpt + '</option>'
        }).join('');
        $attribute.html(html)
       });

        ('select[name*="[]"]').change(function () {
        var $size = $('select').next('.size');
        var product = $(this).val(), sizeProd = size[product] || [];

        var htmlS = $.map(sizeProd, function(sProd){
            return '<option value="' + sProd + '">' + sProd + '</option>'
        }).join('');
        $size.html(htmlS)
        });
       });
    });
```

and html code here:

```
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option></option>
        <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
        <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
        <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
        <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    <select name="size[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm size">
    </select>
   <input name="number[]" type="text" style="width: 50px"/>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option></option>
        <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
        <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
        <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
        <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    <select name="size[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm size">
    </select>
   <input name="number[]" type="text" style="width: 50px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, can I know why you unapproved my answer ?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I can't approve both answers. Both are working for me.

Comment: I perfectly undestand, but the thing is that you approved mine first then you disapproved. If you've approved the other answer without mine I will not asked for approving. Nevermind thanks for your honesty :)

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi I'm using your code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `html` code is going wrong cause you're using two `select` with same id:

```
<select name="att[]" id="attribute" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">

<select name="product[]" id="product" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
```

Then I correct your I correct your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o01y4x2y/4/) here & it's working fine

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('select[name*="[]"]').each(function(){
             
            var attribute = {
            'shoes': ['standard'],
            'trous': ['male', 'female'],
            'shirt': ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow'],
            'hoodie': ['blue', 'red'],
            }
     
            
                        
 var size = {
            'shoes': ['35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46'],
            'trous': ['44', '46', '48', '50', '52', '54', '56', '58', '60', '62', '64'],
            'shirt': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
            'hoodie': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
        }


            $('select[name*="[]"]').change(function () {
            var $attribute = $(this).next('.attribute');
             var $size = $(this).next('.attribute').next('.size');
             
            var product = $(this).val(), lcns = attribute[product] || [];
           var product22 = $(this).val(), lcns22 = size[product] || [];
            
            var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn){
                return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
            }).join('');
           
              
            var html2 = $.map(lcns22, function(lcn){
                return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
            }).join('');
           
            $attribute.html(html);
            $size.html(html2);
            });
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option></option>
        <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
        <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
        <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
        <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    <select name="size[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm size">
    </select>
   <input name="number[]" type="text" style="width: 50px"/>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option></option>
        <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
        <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
        <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
        <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    <select name="size[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm size">
    </select>
   <input name="number[]" type="text" style="width: 50px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If I want to add another select with name=size[] and will be dependent also on product with options - shoes: 35, 36, ... shirt: S, M, ... Can you help me with it?

Comment: @tomas update your question code & i'll update my answer to help you

Comment: My code is updated and already using your code from this post.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code works for you. The `id` for each HTML element should be unique and so I removed `id=product` and `id=attribute` for `select` elements. Updated JS code to get handle to `attribute` select as follows:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".attribute");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.product').each(function () {

  var attribute = {
   'shoes': ['standard'],
   'trous': ['male', 'female'],
   'shirt': ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow'],
   'hoodie': ['blue', 'red'],
  }

  $('.product').change(function () {
   var $attribute = $(this).parent().siblings().find(".attribute");
   var product = $(this).val(), lcns = attribute[product] || [];

   var html = $.map(lcns, function (lcn) {
    return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
   }).join('');
   $attribute.html(html)
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="input" action="test.php" method="post">

<div class="">
 <span>
  <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
   <option></option>
   <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
   <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
   <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
   <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
  </select>
 </span>
 <span>
  <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
  </select>
 </span>
 <span><input name="number" type="text" style="width: 50px" /></span>
</div>

<div class="">
 <span>
  <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
   <option></option>
   <option value="shoes">Boots</option>
   <option value="trous">Trousers</option>
   <option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
   <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
  </select>
 </span>
 <span>
  <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
  </select>
 </span>
 <span><input name="number" type="text" style="width: 50px" /></span>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```